# Keeping the order of the array in check in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting

There are a lot of algorithms that do sorting in an efficient way, and I was wondering 
if there are efficient ways of outputting the order of the array after sorting.

For instance, let's say we have

`a[5]= {1, 7, 5, 4, 10}`

so `a[0]=1`, `a[1]=7`, `a[2]=5`, `a[3]=4`, `a[4]=10`

then after sorting it becomes

`{1, 4, 5, 7, 10}`, but instead of `{1, 4, 5, 7, 10}` being the output,

let's assume we want `{0, 3, 2, 1, 4}` as the output

(as `{1=a[0], 4=a[3], 5=a[2], 7=a[1], 10=a[4]}` )

Is there an efficient way of doing it when the array is really large?

(or some data structure that helps doing it?)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, let's try not to make too many assumptions. Can you alter the array? Are there predefined restrictions on what the array must contain? The immediately obvious implementation is that of pairing a value with its index, and sorting those pairs. Is this acceptable? It's going to be O(n) extra space - does "efficient" mean space efficiency as well as time efficiency? @user2040251's response seems to suggest a decent method, as long as it's acceptable.

Comment: I seriously don't understand why I keep getting negative votes on all my questions. Is this the type of question that's NOT supposed to be asked? Is my question too vague? At least, I wanna know what's the problem with asking questions like this, then I'll stop asking.

Comment: I couldn't say for sure, as I haven't downvoted you. I'd imagine that displaying proof of some sort of initial effort would help. People tend to get a little upset when a question looks more like a homework prompt than a request for collaboration. What have you tried so far?

Comment: David Frye  I created another array of integers of same length (named key), and tried to keep track of order using that array, and it worked, but it looked a bit cumbersome, so I was just wondering if there was a data structure that keeps track of it automatically.

Comment: So you kept two separate arrays, one of keys and one of values? I believe that @user2040251 is suggesting (and if they aren't, I am) that you consider keeping _one_ array containing pair values. As I understand it, you'd want the key to be the index where the value begins, and the value to be the number (always an integer?) itself.

Comment: David Frye  yeah. that's correct. I think I got it now. Thanks. I was just confused why I got the negative vote for the question (and other questions I asked).

Comment: No worries. If you're confused by the reception of a community, just check and make sure you understand and have followed their rules. Often times, it's easy to look over these things if you're simply set on solving your problem ASAP.

Comment: You could make a seperate array of indices as you suggest. Initialize it to `b[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}`. Then sort it. Except define your sort order as comparing the values of whatever is indexed. For instance comparing elements `i` and `j` would consist of `a[b[i]] < a[b[j]]`. When it's all done, `b` is "sorted" and `a` is unmodified. So you're only sorting one array, not two. You can do this by calling any standard sort algorithm and passing in your own compare function that does the "right thing" in your case, it can be a function-object if you need to hide a pointer to `a` in it.

Answer (score 3):

It can easily be done with an vector of `std::pair`s:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int,std::size_t>> toSort = {{value1,0},{value2,1}};
std::sort(toSort.begin(),toSort.end());
```

Then you can just output `toSort[i].second` for all elements of the vector. Note that `std::pair` overloads `operator<` on a sensible way which is why you do not need to provide a custom compare function. This is just as efficient as a stable sort, and elements of the same value will keep their original order.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort an array of pairs(value, initial index).

Answer (score 1):

Decades ago I produced a revised `qsort()` to:
1. take a swap function parameter (in addition to the compare function parameter)
2. modified both parameter function parameters to take indexes (of the array) rather than pointers

With these modifications, it is easy to handle an array of indexes which, when the sort is done, is exactly the result you want:

```
int data[N];  // the data to reorder
int indices[N];
for (int j = 0;  j < N;  ++j)  indices [j] = j;

int cmp_f (int j1, int j2)
{
     return data [indices[j1]] - data [indices[j2]];
}

void swap_f (int j1, int j2)
{
     int t = indices [j1];
     indices [j1] = indices [j2];
     indices [j2] = t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a seperate array of indices as you suggest. Initialize it to `b[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}`. Then sort it. Except define your sort order as comparing the values of whatever is indexed. For instance comparing elements `i` and `j` would consist of `a[b[i]] < a[b[j]]`. When it's all done, `b` is "sorted" and `a` is unmodified. So you're only sorting one array, not two. You can do this by calling any standard sort algorithm and passing in your own compare function that does the "right thing" in your case, it can be a function-object if you need to hide a pointer to a in it.

For instance here is a simple implementation using lambdas in C++11:

```
  #include <algorithm>
  ...
  const unsigned a[] = { 1, 7, 5, 4, 10 };
  const unsigned s   = sizeof a / sizeof *a;

  unsigned b[s];
  std::for_each(b, b + s, [&](unsigned &n){ n = &n - b; });
  std::sort(b, b + s, [&](unsigned lhs, unsigned rhs){return a[lhs] < a[rhs]; });
```

After the call:
`b[] = {0, 3, 2, 1, 4}` and `a` is unmodified.